# .aspx page . Setting NavigatUrl to the result of a function in the .cs file. For a noobie

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, output

I have a file Approval.aspx

and here is the code

```
 <asp:MenuItem Text="Attachments" Value="Attachments" 
                NavigateUrl="PropertyInfo.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
```

In the corresponding Approval.aspx.cs file

I have the following code

```
protected String AfeAttachment
{
    get { return String.Format("{0}/{1}?txtAFENumber={2}", mod.BaseURL, "AFEWellFileAttachment.aspx", afeNumber); }
}
```

Rather than having the navigate url be set to the propertyinfo.aspx,I want it set to the results of AFEattachment.

How do I do this?

Comment: anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the NavigateUrl from within the Page_Load event i.e.

```
Menu1.Items[0].NavigateUrl = AfeAttachment;
```